# Can you use Carbon Framework with Alloy Framework?

Tags: titanium-mobile, macos-carbon, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-alloy

Is it possible to use [**Carbon Framework**](http://carbon.appersonlabs.com/) with [**Alloy Framework**](http://projects.appcelerator.com/alloy/docs/Alloy-bootstrap/index.html#) in Appcelerator Titanium ?

Answer (score 1):

yes... Carbon appears to only be a UI framework while Alloy in UI and MVC

Comment: how can you prove that ? ... are you make a test ?